# How can I check the progress of a HttpWebRequest upload?

Tags: c#, wpf, httpwebrequest

I wonder how do I check how much of a file has been uploaded/downloaded? I am using `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: Then are you *not* also handling the buffering yourself when writing/reading to the input/output streams of `HttpWebRequest`?  By buffering, you have a natural iteration with which to increment progress.

Comment: I maybe wrong but all that buffering will be progress on the client side only right? not data I actually send over. or do you have some code or links for me to see what you mean? btw my current code looks something like http://codepad.org/gK16e0NU

Comment: See **[http://stackoverflow.com/a/2604279/240845](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2604279/240845)** for code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight 4 RC File Upload with Upload Progress: how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529558/silverlight-4-rc-file-upload-with-upload-progress-how-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this is you use async mode on the `HttpWebRequest` - there is a working sample (based on the MSDN doc sample code) [here](http://stuff.seans.com/2009/01/05/using-httpwebrequest-for-asynchronous-downloads/).  Brief description:

> Here’s a little Win Forms client that
>   allows you to download a single file
>   from a server, using either HTTP or
>   FTP.  It shows download progress and
>   displays the average transfer rate, in
>   kb/sec.  It also demonstrates how to
>   use the HttpWebRequest and
>   FtpWebRequest classes in System.Net to
>   do file downloads.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you set either HttpWebRequest.ContentLength or HttpWebRequest.SendChunked before calling GetRequestStream, the data you send will be sent to the server with each call to Stream.[Begin]Write. If you write the file in small chunks suggests, you can get an idea of how far along you.

Comment: Actually, the client buffers the data even when you set SendChunked. I tried this with an 18M file and it all sent in a few seconds, then the actual transmission took minutes.

Answer (score -2):

You have to call it asynchronously to update the progress of your upload/download.

HttpWebRequest have methods like

```
public override IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
public override IAsyncResult BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
```

accepting asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Thank you but can you elaborate abit on how you would do this.

Comment: The callback is for when the request is done.  there's no progress via the callback (other than 100%--which is likely *not* why the OP asked the question).  that might explain the downvote