# POST using HttpWebRequest callback not fired when response from POST is a redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, http, httpwebrequest

I am trying to call a POST operation from Silverlight. My post is handled by an MVC3 controller, which returns a Redirect once it's finished processing the POST data. I use the HttpWebRequest object and everything works fine.

I want to be able to monitor and report the progress of the POST as it is uploading a large file. I have started by implementing a variation of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529558/silverlight-4-rc-file-upload-with-upload-progress-how-to).

My problem occurs when I set request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering to false. My async callback method is never fired.

If I change the POST handler to not return the redirect, everything works as expected again.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

Here is my code

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new 
Uri("http://localhost:3399/items/upload"));

request.Method = "POST";
string boundary = "---------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

request.ContentLength = CalculatePostLength();

request.BeginGetRequestStream(asyncResult =>
{
  Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
  var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

  //Write filename
  writer.WriteLine(boundarySeparator);
  writer.WriteLine(nameheader);
  writer.WriteLine();
  writer.WriteLine(title);

  //Write file
  writer.WriteLine(boundarySeparator);
  writer.WriteLine(fileHeader);
  writer.WriteLine(contentType);
  writer.WriteLine(contentLength);
  writer.WriteLine();
  writer.Flush();
  Stream output = writer.BaseStream;
  Stream input = fileToUpload.OpenRead();
  var buffer = new byte[4096];
  for (int size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
       size > 0;
       size = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
  {
      output.Write(buffer, 0, size);
  }
  output.Flush();
  writer.WriteLine();

  writer.WriteLine(boundaryCompleter);
  writer.Flush();                                                       

  stream.Close();
  request.BeginGetResponse(ReadHttpResponseCallback, request);


}, request);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the browser HTTP stack instead of the client stack? There's an open bug about that in SL4.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `HttpWebRequest` class will automatically follow any redirects. I'm going to *suspect* that this is causing the issue.

To get around it, set [`httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to `false`. The default is `true`.

Once the response has been returned, you will then be responsible for checking if the status code is 301, 302, 303 or 307, retrieving the value of the `Location` header and then executing the redirect yourself. In the case of Silverlight, the redirect would most likely correlate to a page level navigation, so this is something you'd need to take care of manually anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's great, just not for Silverlight. I probably should have specified in my question that I went down this path already. The problem is that AllowAutoRedirect is not implemented in Silverlight; so setting it to false simply throw a NotImplementedException.

Comment: I even checked the MSDN docs to see the member was defined. :(

Ugh. *shakes fist at Silverlight being useless*

Comment: The devil is in the details :-)

Platform Notes
Silverlight 4:
 - Do not use this member when targeting Silverlight 4.